# Clojure Lein can't find Oracle JDBC Driver

Tags: oracle, maven, jdbc, clojure, leiningen

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB using Clojure/Lein.

I downloaded the ojdbc.jar from here:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven1/oracle-jdbc/jars/

I then installed it to my local repo using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\dev\tools\ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=9.2.0.5 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

My project.clj looks like this:

```
(defproject spike "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "spike"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.0-alpha4"]
                [compojure "1.1.5"]
                [ring/ring-json "0.1.2"]
                [oracle/classes12dms "9.0.4"]
                [com.oracle/ojdbc14 "9.2.0.5"]
        ]

  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.5"] [lein-deps-tree "0.1.2"]]
  :ring {:handler spike.handler/app}
   :repositories [["internal" "http://xxx:8080/artifactory/repo"] 
                 ["jboss" "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public"]
                 ["jboss-dep" "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated"] ]

  )
```

And the accessing spikeDb.clj looks like this:

```
(ns spike.spikeDb
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [clojure.java.jdbc.sql :as sql])
  (:import  java.sql.Types))

(def devdb {:classname "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            :subprotocol "oracle"
            :subname "thin:xxx/xxx@xxx:1528/xxx"})

(defn get-xxx [id]
 (jdbc/query devdb
   (sql/select [:TITLE :DESCRIPTION]
             :XXX (sql/where {:CODE id}))))
```

I load the server using

```
lein ring server
```

But when I navigate to that page I get this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:xxx/xxx@xxx:1528/xxx
DriverManager.java:604  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
DriverManager.java:190  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
jdbc.clj:206    clojure.java.jdbc/get-connection
jdbc.clj:628    clojure.java.jdbc/db-with-query-results*
jdbc.clj:646    clojure.java.jdbc/query
RestFn.java:425 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
spikeDb.clj:13  spike.spikeDb/get-xxx
```

What am I doing wrong??!

Comment: In plain Java, it's often a good idea to do a `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` in case the automatic driver registration did not work. It looks like your db library might be already doing that, but give it a try. It would also allow you to get rid of the class name string literal (to be replaced with a compiler-checked class literal).

Comment: Try to print the dependency tree of you project with mvn dependency:tree to make sure that oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is in your classpath.

Comment: You can also use  [ lein deps :tree ] to print the dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks Chiron - I can confirm it is there

Comment: Looks like maybe there's an error loading the driver. Try adding `(Class/forName "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` in the top level of your namespace and see if that throws any exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with the same error. The only way I've found to make this work is to *not* use a maven `groupId` of `com.oracle`, but instead something else like `local`.

Try this (note the new groupId):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\dev\tools\ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=local -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=9.2.0.5 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

And then reference the ojdbc dependency in `project.clj` like so:

```
[local/ojdbc14 "9.2.0.5"]
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to download the latest Oracle driver and install it with lein 2 in your local repository, is using the [lein-localrepo](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo) plugin:

To use it, edit your `~/.lein/profiles.clj` and add `{:user {:plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.5.3"]]}}`

Now from the commandline use it to install the driver into your local repository

```
lein localrepo install -r D:\Path\To\Repo\
                          D:\Path\To\ojdbc6.jar
                          oracle.jdbc/oracledriver "12.1.0.1"
```

Now you can reference it in your project.clj, together with clojure.java.jdbc.

```
(defproject spike "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.3"]
                 [oracle.jdbc/oracledriver "12.1.0.1"]])
```

Looking at your current db-spec, I notice that the driver class, subprotocol and subname are incorrect

```
(ns spike.spikedb
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]))

(def db
  {:classname    "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   :subprotocol  "oracle:thin"
   :subname      "//@hostname:port:sid"
   :user         "username"
   :password     "password"}))

(jdbc/query db ["select ? as one from dual" 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

How does one make Oracle JDBC drivers available to Clojure/Leiningen?

1. Download ojdbc7.jar from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index.html
2. mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgeneratePom=true﻿
3. in project.clj:

   :dependencies [ ...
                   [com.oracle/ojdbc "12.1.0.2"]
                    ... ]

*adjust the above as needed for the current ojdbc version if not 12.1.0.2*